# Install JSTL jar package to a JSP project

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I try to implement the for loop from the Java Standard Tag Library as follows:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${car.totalNumberOfCars - 1}" >                                   
    <a  class="car-link" href="model.jsp?id=${car.cars[0].carId}" id="${car.cars[0].carId}" >
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
                    <div class="thumbnail parts"> 
                        <img src="${car.cars[0].carImg}" alt="..." height="300"/>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h1>${car.cars[0].carName}</h1>
                            <p> ${car.cars[0].carDesc}</p>                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </a>                                    
        </div>   
</c:forEach>
```

However, I get the following error printed on the console:

```
  error: package org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core does not exist
```

Comment: looks like you either have not included the jstl library or the import in your jsp...

Comment: I have imported it too. I did  not include that segment of the code to this post.

Comment: is it a maven project? If not, do you have the .jar jstl file inside your lib folder? And can you post the code for the import you have on your jsp?

Comment: Jonathan, I have added the segment of code that has the import of the library.

Comment: ok that looks fine, are you sure you have added the jstl .jar file to your lib folder ?

Comment: Do I need to add the jar file to the libraries? (Like adding mysql jdbc driver).
However, I have run a number of projects without attaching a jar file.

Comment: yes, unless you have a project management tool like maven where it will do this for you (providing you have specified the library in the pom.xml).. if you do not have maven, then yes, you need to add it like your mysql driver

Comment: you can download the jar from here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Javabean construct car, but Jonathan's answer was correct though.

```
 <% car.setCars();
                for (int i = 0; i < car.getTotalNumberOfCars(); i++) {
                   out.println("<a  class=\"car-link\" href=\"model.jsp?id="+ car.cars[i].getCarId()+"\" id"+ "=\"" +car.cars[0].getCarId() + "\">");
                   out.println("<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-3\"> ");
                   out.println("<div class=\"thumbnail parts\">");
                   out.println("<img src=\""+ car.getCars()[i].getCarImg()+ "\" alt=\"...\""+ " height=\"300\">");
                   out.println("<div class=\"caption\"");
                   out.println("<h1>"+car.getCars()[i].getCarName()+"</h1>");
                   out.println("<p>"+car.getCars()[i].getCarDesc()+"</p>");
                   out.println("</div>");
                   out.println("</div>");
                   out.println("</a>");
                   out.println("</div>");

                }
            %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing the .jar file for JSTL

Try download it from here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Then add it to your lib folder inside WEB-INF (or the same place you keep your other .jar files like the mysql driver you mentioned in comments)

Comment: I did that and it worked but I got angry and changed the code, so I no more used the javabeans and wrote it raw (bad practice though).

Comment: Yes it did, Thanks a lot. please can you mail me with any projects that you are handling that I may partake in?

Comment: Nice to hear. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if it helped you solve the problem. And i'm not working on any group based projects currently. The best place to start is by creating your own project to work on, maybe like an interactive website or something.

Comment: working on creating a group though of java web developers, so i can add you to that, will send you a pm on twitter

Comment: can't send people a pm if they aren't following you... contact me via my details found on my profile

Comment: hi please send your twitter handle

Comment: why? i don't really use twitter but here it is @Jonathanlal

Answer (score 0):

You have some tags switched up. You have this simplified structure:

```
<c:forEach>
    <a>
        <div>
            <div>
                <img/>
                <div>
                    <h1></h1>
                    <p></p>                                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>                                    
    </div>   
</c:forEach>
```

But the closing `a` tag and the last closing `div` tag are in the wrong order, flip them around.

Comment: And you think that that causes the error `error: package org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core does not exist` ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I can't ensure that the error will be fixed with this as I am unable to test it. But I have seen in a lot of languages that the compilers complain with generic errors like "Symbol not found" just because you messed the order of tags or the scope of classes and so on up

Comment: @DavidEnoma So you're not getting the error anymore?

Comment: No I am no more getting the errors, thanks Lino